# Get react native IOS .ipa file in windows

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I have written an app which i tried to code that it runs on both `IOS` and `Android` without any special customization for any platform. and now i wanna get `.apk` and `.ipa` files.

i'm using `Windows` and i don't have any access to `Mac`. so is there any way to generate .ipa file in windows? has anybody done this before? i would appreciate any experience.

any tutorial i've seen they use `XCODE` to generate it. there should be a way to this without xcode!

Comment: AFAIK you cant. Apple has restricted access to their resources when you try to compile any mac thing you need an apple device.

Comment: you can generate .ipa file in windows 10 only using **expo** ... but I gotta tell you ... it's going to be really LARGE file about 100mb+

Comment: The only real option (aside from Expo, which isn't applicable to this use case as you've already built the app) is to run Mac OS in a VM and compile the app from there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way. To generate .ipa you must have a Mac and Xcode(aside from expo)